# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > when building APK

Tags: java, android, build, apk

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/AsyncListUtil.class

I am getting this error when trying to build the apk. App is compiling successfully and Apk is not building

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'org.apache.karaf.http:http:3.0.5'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0')
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0@aar") { transitive = 
true }
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile project(':adcolony-sdk-3.1.2')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: use `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'` . For test case remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'`

Comment: it isnt working this way, please help

Answer (score 0):

try to change v4 to v7 at line  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'` like below code

```
     dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.karaf.http:http:3.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:26.0.1' //change here
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0@aar") { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile project(':adcolony-sdk-3.1.2')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**update**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

clean and rebuild.

Comment: its causing an error when i am changing the version from 4 to 7

Comment: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v7:26.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v7:26.0.1.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v7/26.0.1/support-v7-26.0.1.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v7/26.0.1/support-v7-26.0.1.pom'.
            > Connect to 192.168.1.107:3128 [/192.168.1.107] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out).

Comment: but i have already this in my gradle:    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}  should i add an extra url?